# How to rename filename based on cell range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am extracting 12 Excel files for one vendor. I have many vendors with 10 or 12 Excel files.  Every Excel file is a vendor form. Each Excel file has only one sheet, namely “sheet1”. The vendor name is in Cell range (C9:F9) of every Excel file. I want to extract all these 12 Excel files “Sheet1” into one workbook. Then I want to save this new consolidated Excel file with a name based on cell range (C9:F9) i.e. vendor name. I am using the following code. This code is helping me for consolidating the Excel files in one workbook. But I want to change the following line of code...

```
wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\s\Desktop\C\Consolidation", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```

I want the filename to be based on cell range(C9:F9) like
Consolidation_XYZ (XYZ is vendor name which is in C9:F9).

The Code is :

```
Sub ImportFiles()
Dim wbOpen As Workbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim fName As String
'Change Path
Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\s\Desktop\A\"
Dim strExtension As String
MsgBox ("Do you Want to Extract Files?")
'Comment out the 3 lines below to debug
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
On Error Resume Next
    ChDir strPath
    'Change extension
    strExtension = Dir("*.xls")
      Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    'Change Path, Name and File Format
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\s\Desktop\C\Consolidation", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
          Do While strExtension <> ""
            Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
                  With wbOpen
                .Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("F6")
                wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Name = wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With            
            strExtension = Dir            
        Loop
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
On Error GoTo 0
MsgBox ("Files Extracted Succussfully")
fName = Dir("C:\Users\s\Desktop\A\*.*")
Do While fName <> ""
If fName <> "Master1.xls" And fName <> "Master2.xls" Then  'or .txt or .csv or whatever
Kill "C:\Users\s\Desktop\A\" & fName
End If
fName = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you provided can create the new independent variable in which you can store the value of Range "C9:F9" and use the same while opening the file to store the name file means range "C9:F9" and use the same when you save the file.

Comment: but how to change Filename:="C:\Users\s\Desktop\C\Consolidation", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal Do While strExtension <> "" Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)

Comment: Do you want to change consolidated file name or just want to add the name of all vendors with sheet in consolidated file. Because if there are different vendors then there is no meaning to change the consolidated file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Declare a string variable for the file name:

```
Dim strVndr as String
```

Assign the vendor name to the variable...
For Office365:

```
strVndr=application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin("_",False, range("C9:F9"))
```

Otherwise, try:

```
strVndr=application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(Range("C9"),"_",Range("D9"),"_",Range("E9"),"_",Range("F9"))
```

Then modify your original SaveAs line to combine your path and file name (note I added a final backslash to your original filename line):

```
wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\s\Desktop\C\Consolidation\" & strVndr, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
```